# Video file moves to folder but does not upload to database

Tags: php, mysql

So my video file i upload successfully uploads to the folder but it will not upload in my phpmyadmin table i have created for my video_upload system. I cannot find a solution to this problem so any help is appreaciated. P.s. I'm fairly new to databases

If more code needs to be provided let me know, here is my whole index.php file
My program does not receive any errors

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Upload System</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css' />
</head>
<body>
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
?>

<div class='box'>
    <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <?php
        if(isset($_FILES['video'])){

            $name = $_FILES['video']['name'];
            $type = explode('.', $name);
            $type = end($type);
            $size = $_FILES['video']['size'];
            $random_name = rand();
            $tmp = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];

            if($type != 'mp4' && $type != 'MP4' && $type != 'flv') {
                $message = "Video Format Not Supported !";
            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'videos/'.$random_name.'.'.$type);
                mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO videos VALUES('', '$name', 'videos/$random_name.$type')");
                $message = "Successfully Uploaded! ";
            }
            echo "$message <br/><br/>";
        }
    ?>  
        Select Video: <br/>
        <input type='file' name='video' />
        <br/><br/>
        <input type='submit' value='Upload' />
    </form>
</div>

<div class='box'>
    <?php
        $run = "";
        $video_id = "";
        $video_url = "";
        $video_name= "";
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT `id`, `name`, `url` FROM videos");
        while($run = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $video_id = $run['id'];
            $video_name = $run['name'];
            $video_url = $run['url'];
        }
    ?>
        <a href='view.php?video= <?php echo $video_url; ?>'>
        <div id='url'>
            <?php echo $video_name; ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: column type and length is?

Comment: what is the value of `$video_url` in the anchor tag? looks like you need to close the anchor tag as well

Comment: and how many columns does your db hold? If it's not matching the number of values, then it's failing.

Comment: you also shouldn't be embedding db code/conditionals inside a form like that; it makes room for some unexpected results at times.

Comment: add `mysqli_error($connection)` to your query; what does that throw back? and are you paying attention to comments here or waiting for a magic answer to suddently appear below? cuz I'm not going to stare at this much longer. It's already been 5 mins. since my first comment and now... well, I left it.

Comment: the column type for id is an int which auto increments and the name and url are varchar with 255 values so i dont think its the column.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `videos` (`id`, `name`, `url`) 
        VALUES ('', '$name', 'videos/$random_name.$type')";
mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```